# error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive] double payCalc(P, yir, y);

Tags: c++

```
 double  payCalc(double P,double  yir, double  y)

 {
    double  mir, a, b, c, d, e, f, Payment;
    mir = yir/1200;
    a = 1+mir;
    b = 1/a;`?`enter code here`
    c = 12*y;
    d = pow(b,c);
    e = 1-d;
    f = P*mir;":?
 return Payment;
  }

   int main ()
 {
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2); //setting 
    double P, yir, y;
    cin>>P>>yir>>y;
    double payCalc(P, yir, y);
    cout<<"Principal: "<<P<<" Interest Rate: "<<yir<<" Years: "<<y<<
    " Payment: "<<payCalc<<endl;
   }
```

calculating house payment and can't get out of the error above.
The payCalc is calculating the payment while the int main() is to insert the varibales into payCalc

Answer (score 1):

The below line of code is a declaration and not a function call

```
double payCalc(P, yir, y);
```

The compiler thinks that you want to declare a variable `payCalc` with type `double` and initialize it. Since you have an expression list instead of a single value or a single expression, the compiler complains with the error:

```
error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
```

Remove the `double` if you want to call the function `payCalc` with the arguments `P, yir, y` like this:

```
payCalc(P, yir, y);
```

Note: There are stray characters in the code you have posted.

Comment: okay! thank you! now the problem is that the return payment statement is bringing back a 1 no matter the calculation.

Comment: @Chaoticflam: This is where a debugger can help you. Please read this post: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)